# Sharing a string via telegram messenger

Tags: android, share, telegram

I want to share my string sentence via Telegram messenger so user should select some contacts (or select all option) to sending my pm to them, I use below method to do this work but this action just lets user to selecting one contact for sharing !

```
void intentMessageTelegram(String msg)
{
    final String appName = "org.telegram.messenger";
    final boolean isAppInstalled = isAppAvailable(this.getApplicationContext(), appName);
    if (isAppInstalled) 
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        myIntent.setPackage(appName);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Kevin"));
    } 
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Telegram not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: no ! i didn't find any way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [URI scheme description](http://telegram.wiki/tips:urischeme) will helps you.